# CGAL: Is 2D poly partitioning supported with epeck kernel?

Tags: cgal

I'd like to use **CGAL convex partitioning** in an application that is based on the **epeck kernel**, but trying to compile such throws the following error:

**error:**

```
 no matching constructor for initialization of 'CGAL::Partition_vertex<CGAL::Partition_traits_2<CGAL::Epeck> >'
```

A simple test case for this is to take, for example, the `greene_approx_convex_partition_2.cpp` example from the distribution and try to change the kernel parameterization to `epeck`.

Are/can the `2D convex partitioning` routines supported on an `epeck` kernel?  Any pointers or advice much appreciated!

thanks much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
--- a/include/CGAL/Partition_2/Indirect_edge_compare.h
+++ b/include/CGAL/Partition_2/Indirect_edge_compare.h
@@ -69,7 +69,7 @@ class Indirect_edge_compare
         else 
         { 
            // construct supporting line for edge
-           Line_2  line = _construct_line_2(*edge_vtx_1, *edge_vtx_2);
+           Line_2  line = _construct_line_2((Point_2)*edge_vtx_1, (Point_2)*edge_vtx_2);
            return _compare_x_at_y_2(*vertex, line) == SMALLER;
         }
      }               
@@ -98,10 +98,10 @@ class Indirect_edge_compare

         // else neither endpoint is shared
         // construct supporting line
-        Line_2  l_p = _construct_line_2(*p, *after_p);
+        Line_2  l_p = _construct_line_2((Point_2)*p, (Point_2)*after_p);
         if (_is_horizontal_2(l_p)) 
         {
-            Line_2  l_q = _construct_line_2(*q, *after_q);
+            Line_2  l_q = _construct_line_2((Point_2)*q, (Point_2)*after_q);

             if (_is_horizontal_2(l_q))  
             {                         
@@ -130,7 +130,7 @@ class Indirect_edge_compare
             return q_larger_x;
         // else one smaller and one larger
         // construct the other line
-        Line_2 l_q = _construct_line_2(*q, *after_q); 
+        Line_2 l_q = _construct_line_2((Point_2)*q, (Point_2)*after_q); 
         if (_is_horizontal_2(l_q))     // p is not horizontal
         {
             return _compare_x_at_y_2((*q), l_p) == LARGER;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed that while `greene_approx_convex_partition_2` with epeck results in the compiler error mentioned above, the alternative `approx_convex_partition_2` compiles just fine with epeck right out of the box.

Comment: Note that CGAL 4.4 will contain a fix to the problem.